# Creating a small Window object simulator similar to a normal Window Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the concept of `this` keyword and its behavior. I would love to know if there is a way that we can create a window object simulator, so that whenever we invoke a method at global level rather than returning window object it returns the simulator that we make.

Jquery is a very good example where the when a `clickHandler` method is called then the object is not the Window object for sure is not what you think it is.

Basically the objective is to run functions in the simulator and not on the Window object.

Comment: Run the script in node, and replace `window` with an empty object?

Comment: have you take at look at Module Pattern???

Comment: I don't think this is possible without actually modifying the JavaScript engine itself.  jQuery does not simulate or replace the `window` object; rather, when it invokes callbacks, it uses `Function#call` or `Function#apply` to change the `this` context.